# FastAPI + Tortoise ORM

Tags: fastapi, tortoise-orm

i am using fastapi with tortoise orm and when i want to add a cart i get this error

## error

if value and not value._saved_in_db:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_saved_in_db'

## models

```
class Cart(BaseModel):
    user = fields.ForeignKeyField('models.User', related_name='user_cart')
    product = fields.ForeignKeyField(
        'models.Product', related_name='product_cart')
    quantity = fields.IntField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        table = 'carts'
        ordering = ('-created',)
```

## schemas

```
class CartCreate(BaseModel):
    product_id: int
    quantity: int = Field(..., ge=0, le=10)


class Cart(BaseModel):
    id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

## routes

```
@router.post('/create', status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_cart(
    cart: CartCreate, 
    user: User = Depends(get_current_user)
) -> CartSchema:
    cart_obj = await Cart.create(
        user=user.id,
        product=cart.product_id,
        quantity=cart.quantity
    )
    return CartSchema.from_orm(cart_obj)
```

what should i do?